# Viability of Typed Arrays in javascript in terms of performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, biginteger, typed-arrays, uint8array

I am in the process of writing a javascript library for multiple precision arithmetic. Essentially, storing a number as an array of digits and applying operations on them.

I have recently discovered javascript's Typed Arrays, and am considering rewriting using something like a `Uint8Array`, and expanding to a new buffer when the size must increase.

Is the performance increase of fixed size `Uint8Array`s worth the performance loss of increasing the buffer via the `TypedArray.prototype.set` method every few operations or so?

Essentially, my question is if it is viable to use typed arrays when dealing with arrays of not-necessarily fixed length

Comment: Performance loss compared to `Array.push`? That’s what it does internally too, at a certain point. Anyway, benchmark it with some real-world use cases to find out.

Comment: Maybe, but currently in javascript the only way to grow a typed array is to create a new buffer and copy over the entire array via `set`

Comment: do you really need to write a library? Chrome 67 has BigInt https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/bigint, also from the same link https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi

Comment: Yes. The built-in library is nice, but I plan to handle the exponent calculation (non-integers), and eventually complex numbers. There are also some more optimizations to be made, namely possibly using typed arrays, hence this post